# Is there a gapless music player for WP?

Tags: apps, music, mediaplayer

Apparently, [some people](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpmusic/gapless-music-playback/dd7426b0-89ae-4420-a609-404e0fbf1303) are very keen on [gapless playback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapless_playback). [Fruit](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1797) seems to think it's important.

So, is there any music player on WP that supports gapless playback?

Does the default player support it? (If not now, then when?)

Comment: I've got to confess, I'm underwhelmed by the WP8 Music app and Windows 8 Music compared to Zune and Windows Phone 7. That stuff just worked. This is a huge step back to me :(

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the windows phone store there is an [app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/subsonic-music-streamer/2eb445a5-ca04-e011-9264-00237de2db9e) that supports gapless playback.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong (or it could be wishful thinking), but I cant say I've noticed gaps between tracks in Spotify.

Granted, it's not just a player, and granted it's a bit pants on WP, but it can play local files in addition to streamed.